# How to create proper login to access trough [Authorize] (MVC database-first)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication

I'm new to MVC and so far I've created some pages. As I only want to let members access to the site I've added `[Authorize]` for these pages so other are redirected to to login/register page. But I've no clue about the next steps.

How do I give authorization upon success login? Do I use session for the current logged user?

I got MVC template which already have its own login, but I want to create my own, using database(database-first) to get better understanding.

Any help is much appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: are you using Asp.net `identity authentication API` or what?

Comment: No idea, trying to find some guides but I just find tutorial for code-first, which I can't use in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Using below article where you can learn how to integrate existing database in `ASP.NET MVC 5` web application using ADO.NET `database first` approach and how to configure simple `login work flow` for integrating existing logins with the ASP.NET MVC 5 web application with `OWIN middle ware` secure `authorization` mechanism.

**Article :** [**Integrating Existing Database With Login Using ADO.NET Database First Approach**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-5-integrating-existing-database-with-login-usin/)

```
    [Authorize]  
    public class HomeController: Controller  
    {  
       public ActionResult Index()  
        {  
            return this.View();  
        }
    }
```

**Note :**

used `[Authorize]` attribute at `controller` level to secure access to `Home controller` for `authenticated users only`.